# Show a single image from array of images

Tags: javascript, jquery

That's all I want to do.  I'm very beginner in javascript but I just don't understand why this wouldn't work.  I've looked across the depths of google but people are asking more complicated things.  I literally just want to show an image I've stored in an array.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var coolImage = new Array();

    coolImage[0] = "images/2.gif";

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = coolImage[0];

    document.write(img);
});
```

All I get on the page is `[object HTMLImageElement]`.

Comment: How would you display an image if you knew the location (without an array)?... Answer that, and you have your answer. You would not write the location - you would instruct the browser to... yes, you can do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The brackets and object name indicate that you are writing the string representation of the Image object to the page. Try replacing `document.write(img);` with:

```
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

An example can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9BUcT/)

Answer (score 1):

You're working with a JavaScript Image object, but you want an Image element:

```
var image = document.createElement("img");
image.src = coolImage[0];
document.body.appendChild(image);
```

Comment: Actually, the JavaScript Image Object is analogous to the HTML Image Element and can be appended directly to the DOM. This is a common method of pre-loading images; see http://jsfiddle.net/9BUcT/ for an example

Comment: @Dave Good tip, I didn't know the representation was interchangeable. Upvote for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you can use:

`$('body').append(img);`